# Bind Jquery Multi-Select values to hidden input box

Tags: jquery

I am having a bit of an issue getting the values of this [mutliselect](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) box.

I have a php foreach looping out each available option which shows up perfectly fine. But when I select an option from the drop down, my hidden field receives every possible value from the drop down instead of the ones I selected. Any help?

```
$('.ui-multiselect-menu input:checkbox').on('change',function() {

            selectedItems = new Array();
            console.log(selectedItems);
            $(".ui-multiselect-menu input:checkbox").each(function() {
                if($.inArray($(this).val(), selectedItems) != 0){
                  selectedItems.push($(this).val());
                }
            });
            console.log(selectedItems);
                var data = selectedItems.join(',');
            $(".live").val(data);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer.

```
$('.ui-multiselect-menu input:checkbox').on('change',function() {

            selectedItems = new Array();
            console.log(selectedItems);
            $(".ui-multiselect-menu input[name=multiselect_0]:checked").each(function() {
                if($.inArray($(this).val(), selectedItems) != 0){
                  selectedItems.push($(this).val());
                }
            });
            console.log(selectedItems);
                var data = selectedItems.join(',');
            $(".live").val(data);
        });
```